# Python memory usage - not freeing variables properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, memory, memory-leaks

I'm writing a script in Python to detect the skew of an image with text.

The two functions below work fine on my local machine, but cause my Heroku dyno to crash due to memory usage exceeding 512MB (sometimes it gets up to >1000MB).

I profiled the script using memory-profiler and the results are below.

For **function #1**, though a lot of memory is allocated, the memory is freed quickly after it is allocated, as I'd expect, and thus is fine.

However **function #2** seems to keep memory allocated for no reason. The variable `coords` is used for 2 lines, yet its memory is never deallocated. Additionally, even when function #2 returns, the 210 MB allocated to it remain "in use".

**Function #1:**

Memory profile for this function (key area is **lines 52-54**, which deallocate memory as expected):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
49    395.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       @profile
50                                 def determine_skew(self):
51    413.1 MiB     17.2 MiB           img = io.imread(self.image, as_grey=True)
--> 52    552.1 MiB    139.0 MiB       edges = canny(img, sigma=self.sigma)
--> 53    554.3 MiB      2.2 MiB       h, a, d = hough_line(edges)
--> 54    429.3 MiB   -125.1 MiB       _, ap, _ = hough_line_peaks(h, a, d, num_peaks=self.num_peaks)
55    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           if len(ap) == 0:
56                                         return { "angle" : 0 }
57    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           absolute_deviations = [self.calculate_deviation(k) for k in ap]
58    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           average_deviation = np.mean(np.rad2deg(absolute_deviations))
59    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           ap_deg = [np.rad2deg(x) for x in ap]
60                             
61    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           bin_0_45 = []
62    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           bin_45_90 = []
63    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           bin_0_45n = []
64    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           bin_45_90n = []
65    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           for ang in ap_deg:
66    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               deviation_sum = int(90 - ang + average_deviation)
67    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               if self.compare_sum(deviation_sum):
68    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB                   bin_45_90.append(ang)
69    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB                   continue
70                                         deviation_sum = int(ang + average_deviation)
71                                         if self.compare_sum(deviation_sum):
72                                             bin_0_45.append(ang)
73                                             continue
74                                         deviation_sum = int(-ang + average_deviation)
75                                         if self.compare_sum(deviation_sum):
76                                             bin_0_45n.append(ang)
77                                             continue
78                                         deviation_sum = int(90 + ang + average_deviation)
79                                         if self.compare_sum(deviation_sum):
80                                             bin_45_90n.append(ang)
81    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           angles = [bin_0_45, bin_45_90, bin_0_45n, bin_45_90n]
82                                     
83    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           lmax = 0
84    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           for j in range(len(angles)):
85    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               l = len(angles[j])
86    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               if l > lmax:
87    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB                   lmax = l
88    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB                   maxi = j
89    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           if lmax:
90    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               ans_arr = self.get_max_freq_elem(angles[maxi])
91    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               ans_res = np.mean(ans_arr)
92                                     else:
93                                         ans_arr = self.get_max_freq_elem(ap_deg)
94                                         ans_res = np.mean(ans_arr)
95                             
96                                     data = {
97    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               "averageDeviation": average_deviation,
98    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               "angle": ans_res,
99    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB               "angleBins": angles
100                                         }
101    429.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           return data
```

**Function #2 (problematic):**

Memory profile (key area is lines **102-104**, which **don't** properly deallocate memory):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
94    181.9 MiB      0.0 MiB       @profile
95                                 def openCVSkewDetect(self):
96                                     # Grayscale image and flip foreground (foreground is now "white", background is "black")
97    185.7 MiB      3.8 MiB           gray = cv2.bitwise_not(self.originalImageOpenCV)
98                                     # Threshold the image, setting all foreground pixels to 255 and background pixels to 0
99    185.7 MiB      0.1 MiB           thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
100    185.7 MiB      0.0 MiB          del gray
101                                    # Grab the (x, y) coordinates of all pixel values > 0, then use these coordinates to compute a rotated bounding box that contains all coordinates
--> 102    325.8 MiB    140.0 MiB      coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
--> 103    325.8 MiB      0.0 MiB      del thresh
--> 104    395.9 MiB     70.1 MiB      angle = copy.copy(cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1])
105                                    # The `cv2.minAreaRect` function returns values in the range [-90, 0); as the rectangle rotates clockwise the returned angle trends to 0 -- in this special case we need to add 90 degrees to the angle
106    395.9 MiB      0.0 MiB          if angle < -45:
107    395.9 MiB      0.0 MiB              angle = -(90 + angle)
108                                    # Otherwise, just take the inverse of the angle to make it positive
109                                    else:
110                                        angle = -angle
111    395.9 MiB      0.0 MiB          print(gc.get_referents(coords))
112    395.9 MiB      0.0 MiB          return angle
```

I've tried `del` to free the memory, `copying` to avoid duplicating references, and returning a constant from function #2, but none of these methods have worked.

Any help or explanation as to why lines 102-104 in function #2 refuse to deallocate memory would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried not having the coords variable, just do the calculation `angle = cv2.minAreaRect(np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0)))[-1])`?

Comment: Any progress? :\

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following method in some of my code, because Python was only queueing memory for garbage collection instead of actually freeing it.

```
# at the start, but it should not matter
import gc 

# after freeing memory
gc.collect()
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried calling the garbage collector after almost every line, but it unfortunately doesn't do anything. It would seem to make sense that this would be the easy solution but I'm not sure why it doesn't work.